# Set focus on input type hidden with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to realize the use case that if someone clicks on `.editReason` the corresponding input field should be focused, but for any reason, it does not work. Maybe you know what I am doing wrong. Many thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<ul id="listOfReasons" class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
     <span class="reasonStatement flex-grow-1" contenteditable="true">
       <input type="hidden" name="reasonStatement[]" value="test">test</span>
       <span class="editReason px-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit">
         <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
       </span>
       <span class="deleteReason">
         <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> 
       </span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#listOfReasons').on('click', '.editReason', function (){
    $(this).siblings('.reasonStatement').find("input[type='hidden'][name^='reasonStatement']").focus()
});
```

Comment: how do you focus an element that is not visible? Hidden inputs are not focusable since there is nothing to focus.

Comment: by any chance, you want to put data on the hidden input that's why you want to focus on it? if not then what's your purpose doing it, we might help you doing it.

Comment: This is clearly an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Alright. Got the point. Thanks for the quick answers!

Comment: So what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @epascarello Just posted the solution. Thanks for your valuable inputs!

Comment: I recommend you close this question as your "answer" makes no sense against the question asked.  I'm glad you got a resolution, but this will not help anyone in the future (imo).

Comment: My guess is you actually wanted to display: none and change that so it is visible and you can focus it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't focus a `<input type="hidden">`, but maybe you want set it focusable swaping to `type="text"` when give click on your icon, and when you blur the input  set it again as `type="hidden"` like this:

```js
$('#listOfReasons').on('click', '.editReason', function () {
  const $input = $(this).siblings('.reasonStatement').find("input[type='hidden'][name^='reasonStatement']")
  $input.prop('type', 'text')
  $input.focus()
});

$('input').on('blur', function () {
  $(this).prop('type', 'hidden')
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="listOfReasons" class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
      <span class="reasonStatement flex-grow-1" contenteditable="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="reasonStatement[]" value="test">test</span>
        <span class="editReason px-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit">
          <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="deleteReason">
          <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> 
        </span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the support. Actually I think I had an issue in the concept. I should not use type hidden, instead textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the input of the members from stackoverflow I realized that there was an issue in the concept. I replaced input type hidden with textarea and it works as expected.

HTML:

```
<ul id="listOfReasons" class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between"> 
    <textarea class="reasonStatement flex-grow-1 border-0" name="reasonStatement[]">test</textarea>
    <span class="editReason px-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit">
      <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="deleteReason">
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#listOfReasons').on('click', '.editReason', function (){
    $(this).siblings('.reasonStatement').focus()
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as asked.  You might have got a resolution to your issue, but not the question.